# mounting a bit by bit copy of a partition in macos

Tags: macos, command-line, filesystem

Is it possible to mount a bit by bit copy of a partition in macos?

I tried with `mount -t apfs backup.img backup/`, but it didnt work. Is there a better way?

Comment: thanks. in this case `backup.img` is a file. Is it possible to mount a image file as a loop device in macos? Otherwise how would you mount a image file in macos?

Comment: What is the format of the image? How did you create it?

Comment: Your question is similar to [How to mount raw disk images?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/129921/how-to-mount-raw-disk-images)

Comment: yes. appreciate it. for whatever reason i was unable to find the answer on google search

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to accomplish mounting at `backup/` by just using the  `hdiutil` command. Say for example, `backup.img` has two APFS volumes named "Tom" and "Bill", then the following command would mount these volumes at `backup/Tom` and `backup/Bill`, respectively.

```
hdiutil attach -mountroot backup/ backup.img
```

Example output from entering the above command is given below.

```
davidanderson@Davids-Mac ~ % cd ~/Desktop 
davidanderson@Davids-Mac Desktop % mkdir backup
davidanderson@Davids-Mac Desktop % hdiutil attach -mountroot backup/ backup.img
/dev/disk2                                              
/dev/disk3              EF57347C-0000-11AA-AA11-0030654 
/dev/disk3s1            41504653-0000-11AA-AA11-0030654 /Users/davidanderson/Desktop/backup/Tom
/dev/disk3s2            41504653-0000-11AA-AA11-0030654 /Users/davidanderson/Desktop/backup/Bill
```

Based on the above output, the command below can be used to eject.

```
hdiutil detach disk2
```

Example output is given below.

```
davidanderson@Davids-Mac Desktop % hdiutil detach disk2                      
"disk2" ejected.
```

If the file name does not use the extension `.dmg` or `.img`, then the  option `-imagekey diskimage-class=CRawDiskImage` must be included. For example, if the filename is `backup.bin`, then enter the following.

```
hdiutil attach -imagekey diskimage-class=CRawDiskImage -mountroot backup/ backup.bin
```

One final note. There does not seem to be the need for the hidden option `-deviceblock` as suggested by Colin Walsh's [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/129921/how-to-mount-raw-disk-images/345179#345179). This probably do to having backed up an APFS partition instead of an entire drive. Anyway, the Device Block Size of APFS containers seem to always be 4096 bytes regardless of the Device Block Size of the Physical Store(s).

Tested using Monterey (macOS 12.5)

Comment: Thanks I will try this

Comment: Does `hdiutil` accept start and end of partition tables?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by *"start and end of partition tables"*. I context of your question, there should be no partition tables, if your `backup.img` file only contains the contents of an entire APFS partition. Here I assume the APFS Container is from a single Physical Store. In other words, there is no Fusion drive arrangement.

Answer (score 2):

The `mount` command does not support mounting from a file directly.

First you will need to create a sort of loopback device that exposes the file as a block device:

```
hdiutil attach -noverify -nomount backup.img
```

Then use

```
diskutil list
```

to find the new device node - and then you can use `mount` to mount the file system on that device.

Comment: Thanks I will try this